# customize material-ui List width

Tags: material-ui

Is there any way to customize material-ui List width? It looks like no matter what width I put in `style` or `innerDivStyle`, it's always maxed out at `350px`. I'd love to see a way to set custom width (like `100%` or whatever arbitrary width) to List. BTW, currently I'm using material-ui `v0.15.0-beta.1`

Comment: can u provide some code?

Comment: It turned out that it's my fault, somewhere nested deep in the style object I had a `maxWidth: 350`, and somehow I didn't capture it. Now I've verified that by setting `width` in `List` component's `style` prop, I can set width whatever way I want. Thanks.